Need Assistance with Deploying a Flutter Web Application on Render.com
I am currently working on deploying a Flutter web application to Render.com and have encountered several challenges that I hope to get some help with. I've followed the typical Flutter web deployment processes but seem to be missing something crucial for Render.com environments.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Build Configuration: I have configured the Flutter build command to generate a web-specific build using flutter build web. This command runs locally without issues and generates the expected build/web directory.
Render Setup: I have set up a new Web Service on Render and pointed it to my GitHub repository containing the Flutter project. I attempted to use the default build settings initially provided by Render.
Deployment Issues: During the deployment process, I receive an error indicating that Flutter is not found in the path (bash: flutter: command not found). It seems like Render's build environment does not have Flutter installed by default.

Render.com do not support flutter. If you want to deploy flutter web, you need to make the web folder inside build folder using command flutter build web. After that go to gitignore and remove reference to this web folder in gitignore so that the build folder can be pushed and will not be ignored. After that in Render.com point to this build/web folder. It is like deploying already build static web in js and html to Render.com

That would have been a great answer
